# How to gray-out cells when N/A is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel sheet used as an order form.

I need to know how to gray out a number of cells if an N/A is entered.

My problem is that if an N/A is entered in to cell D13, cells E13 to E15 to gray out, as well.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you include an image? You can do this through conditional formatting using an IF statement. If you include an image I can provide a better example.  Your cells just have a goofy layout from what you said is all.

Comment: @EricF This is a good answer... Why not propose it as one?

Comment: I just wanted an answer to my question since I like to ensure my answer is correct and accurate is all.

Answer (score 1):

Select cell **E13** and click Conditional formatting > new rule. Select "Use a formula..." :

```
=$D$3="N/A"
```

Then set your formatting to make the background gray as you require.

You can then drag copy the formatting into cells **E14** and **E15**